# Capacitor google maps with Angular stay black on android

Tags: android, angular, google-maps, ionic5, capacitor-plugin

I'm using the [google-maps capacitor plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/google-maps#usage).

I have follow the step to create the map and this is working on my browser running `ionic s` but is black on android.

Does somebody have the same problem ?

#### Analysed

1. This isn't the `--background: transparent` solution since the code stay empty
   [image: List item]
2. I've added the following restriction
   [image]
3. I've added the api Key in both, in the map `creat({...apiKey: MAP_CONFIG.googleApiKey})` and also in the `AndroidManifest.xml` -> `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="MY_API_KEY" />`

But it is just staying black without any errors..

Do somebody have any Idea?